# Dynamic pass product id to REST API in angular 2

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, angular2-forms

I'm trying to update existing products based on id.

Create API for the same.

Call the API in the Angular 2 front end service.

I am passing the API as http://localhost:5000/products/596df0ffcb429a586ef6c0bf

in my postman, data is updating

**routes/products.js**

```
/* UPDATE PRODUCT */
  Products.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body, function (err, post) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.json(post);
  });
});
```

Im stuck in passing the product ID dynamically in the service.

In my component file i have:

```
onSaveConfirm(event) {
if (window.confirm('Are you sure you want to save?')) {
  var prodId=event.newData['_id']

  this.productService.productUpdate(event.newData, prodId).subscribe(data => {
    if (data.success) {
      console.log('Edited success')
     } else {
      console.log('failure edited...')
    }
  });
  event.confirm.resolve(event.newData);
} else {
  event.confirm.reject();
}

}
```

In my service:

```
 //Update product based on id
  productUpdate(products, prodId){

 let prodDet = {
  productDetail: products,
  productId: prodId,
}

let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
return this.http.post('http://localhost:5000/products', { prodDet }, { headers: headers })
  .map(res => res.json());
}
```

I get http://localhost:5000/products not found cause im not passing the id at the end of the URL.

How do i pass the ID here!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are truly using angular 2 use Angular cli to create your application.  This should give you the infrastructure you need.

Also this is tagged as angularjs not angular (angularjs is angular 1.x not 2)

Comment: I hav updated the question , now i just need to pass the product id dynamically in the REST API...pls suggest on the same